# Do we have $\overline{\bigcup\{A_\beta: \beta<\alpha\}}=\bigcup\{ \overline{A_\beta}: \beta<\alpha\}$

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, ordinals

Let $\alpha$ be any ordinal, and for the family $\{A_\beta: \beta< \alpha\}$, we have $A_{\beta_1}\subset A_{\beta_2}$ when $\beta_1<\beta_2<\alpha$, then do we  have $$\overline{\bigcup\{A_\beta: \beta<\alpha\}}=\bigcup\{ \overline{A_\beta}: \beta<\alpha\}$$

Thanks ahead:)

Comment: What are $A_\alpha$? Sets of...?

Comment: Sets of $\omega_2$

Comment: Ah. I just left my mind-reading hat in my other pants, so I couldn't have guessed this from your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A_\beta=[0,\beta)$, then $\bar A_\beta=[0,\beta]$.

If $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal then $$\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha}\bar A_\beta=[0,\alpha)\neq[0,\alpha]=\overline{\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha} A_\beta}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I could ask more, in what spaces, such claim is true? Could you take an example?

Comment: Here are two examples: discrete spaces, and trivial spaces (i.e. spaces with the trivial topology).

Comment: Hahahahahahahahahahaha

Comment: ?${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @Simple For example, your desired conclusion holds if the family $\{A_\beta\}_{\beta\lt\alpha}$ is locally finite (and this doesn't require the monotonicity assumption).